# Force Firefox to use HTTPS for every connection

Tags: firefox, https, firefox-extensions

Is there an addon to force good 'ol firefox to append an 's' at the end of the http on the url bar, so all connections could be https?

I know not every server has SSL, but in case they do, is there a way to force Firefox to use it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few. The most popular ones would be [HTTPS Finder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/https-finder/) or [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere), for instance.

Comment: The first add-on apparently has been removed

Comment: -1. It's dangerous to think that HTTPS Everywhere does what you claim. HTTPS Everywhere only enforces HTTPS for the sites on its whitelist.